# Beginner C exercise [sscanf - fgets - if else]

Tags: c, if-statement, char, fgets, scanf

I'm dealing with a beginner C exercise, i've done the first part pretty correct I think (not elegant at all); if a score is inserted the correct mark is outputted. 
But i Really can't succeed in the last part of the exercise (add plus or minus) and I can't figure out why.
I really would like to understand why `line[1]` does not work as expected.

The text of the exercise:
A professor generates letter grades using the following table:

```
0–60  -> F
61–70 -> D
71–80 -> C
81–90 -> B
91–100 -> A
```

Given a numeric grade, print the letter.
Now, modify the previous program to print a + or – after the letter grade, based on the last digit of the score.
Last digit Modifier

```
1–3 -> "–"
4–7 -> <blank>
8–0 -> "+"
```

For example, 81=B-, 94=A, and 68=D+. Note: An F is only an F. There is no F+ or F-.

What I've done:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

char line[20];              //prepare the input from keyboard
int score;
char plusminus;

int main() {
    printf("insert your score: ");      // ask for the score
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%d", &score);

// check for conditions
    if (score <= 60) {
        printf("F");
    }
    if (score <= 70 && score >60) {
        printf("D");
    }
    if (score <= 80 && score >70) {
        printf("C");
    }
    if (score <= 90 && score >80) {
        printf("B");
    }
    if (score <= 100 && score >90) {
        printf("A");
    }

// plus and minus to the mark, but didn't succed :(
    plusminus = line[1];
    if (plusminus < "3") {
        printf("-");
    }
    if (plusminus > "8") {
        printf("+");
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Double quotes - `"3"` - will create a string containing `3\0` (that `\0` is a nul terminatory - how C knows where the end of the string is). Single quotes - `'3'` - will place the character's value in memory - 51.

Comment: Just a general suggestion here: separate logic from input/output. How to do that? Create new fuction for example "translateScoreToGrade", that has integer as input, and struct Grade as an output (char grade, char modifier). It's much more elegant, and much cleaner to test, and your professor will give you a higher score :)

Comment: Also you can convert those ifs to switch -> (100 - score)/10, case 0 ->A case 1->B ... default->F

Comment: Doesn't `if (plusminus < "3") {` generate a compiler warning? If not, enable all compiler warnings - it saves time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a *string* with a character. A string literal is a pointer to the actual string array in memory. A character is a small integer.

You should use *character* literals instead, using *single* quotes like e.g. `'3'`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already got your score as an `int`, you could use the modulus operator `%` to get the remainder of the score divided by 10 which is the same thing as the last digit.

For example:

```
if((score % 10) <= 3)&&((score % 10) >= 1))
  {
  printf("-");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the first chain of ifs:

```
// check for conditions
if (score <= 60) {
    printf("F");
} else if (score <= 70) {
    printf("D");
} else if (score <= 80) {
    printf("C");
} else if (score <= 90) {
    printf("B");
} else {
    printf("A");
}
```

And handle +/- like this:

```
if ((score - 1) % 10 < 2) {
    printf("-");
} else if ((score - 1) % 10 > 7) {
    printf("+");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   plusminus = line[1];   
if (plusminus < '3'&&plusminus!='0') {
    printf("-");
}
if (plusminus > '8'||plusminus=='0') {
    printf("+");
}
```

you also need to check for '0' because it is < 3 but it output should be '+' according to the rule .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last digit of a base 10 number, use `i % 10`. Then you can make comparisons to this number using integers rather than characters, which is what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int grade=0;
    printf("Enter your grade\n");
    scanf("%d",&grade);

    if (grade<=60) {
        printf("F\n");
    }
    if (grade>=61^grade>=70) {
        printf("D\n");
    }
    if (grade>=71^grade>=80) {
        printf("C\n");
    }
    if (grade>=81^grade>=90) {
        printf("B\n");
    }
    if (grade>=91^grade>=100) {
        printf("A\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char * scoreToGrade(int);

int main(){
    int score;
    printf("Enter your score:");
    scanf("%d",&score);

    char * grade = scoreToGrade(score);

    printf("Grade: %s\n", grade);
}

char * scoreToGrade(int score){
    /*
     * 1 character for the letter
     * 1 character for the +/- (if it's there, otherwise a terminating
     * character, and 1 last character if there was a +/- 
     */
    char * result = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);

    if(score <= 60){
        result[0] = 'F';
    } else if(score <= 70){
        result[0] = 'D';
    } else if(score <= 80){
        result[0] = 'C';
    } else if(score <= 90){
        result[0] = 'B';
    } else {
        result[0] = 'A';
    }

    /* Handle plusses and minuses if the grade is not an F */
    if(result[0] != 'F'){
        int subscore = (score - 1) % 10;
        if(subscore >= 7){
            result[1] = '+';
        } else if(subscore <= 2){
            result[1] = '-';
        } else {
            result[1] = '\0'; /* Add a string terminator, making the string one character long */
        }
    } else {
        result[1] = '\0'; /* Add a string terminator, making the string one character long. This is separate because the 'F' forces a one-character grade */
    }
    /* This is stuck on so that if there is a '+' or '-', the string does not go un-terminated. */
    result[2] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```